# issue with easychair for tracking communications with authors

Tags: paper-submission

I have a problem when using easychair that after searching on the web, I was not able to find an answer to it.

The thing is that after we sent a review and a notification to the authors, about the state of their papers (accepted or rejected), we as the PC did not receive any notification about the decision we have sent. I mean on our email account that is linked to easychair. Is there any way to get the emails that we have sent to the authors? I mean any option on easychair.

Thanks

Comment: Have you contacted easychair? That would seem logical...

Comment: yes, and no response at all

Comment: @SolarMike EasyChair does not provide support unless the conference buys an executive license.